# Form View control Ajax paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, formview

I'm just wondering if anyone can help with this problem I have?

I have a form view and don't like the current paging that is provided by microsoft. So in the pagertemplate I am adding a button in for Next, Previous etc. Is it possible to create an ajax paging method without using the horrible update panels? Is it possible to have a pager method that gets the event args etc?

When the user clicks next it should populate the form view and two other controls on the page. So say I click next to go to page two, this will get the ID from the List, this Id should also be passed onto the other controls on the page.

Also, if anyone has any suggestions for using a better control please let me know!

If anyone has an answer, suggestion or site that could help, please let me know!

thanks all!!

Louis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's your javascript?  This kind of thing is quite trivial once you get used to writing ajax calls from javascript.  I'd recommend using something like jquery as a wrapper around the ajax call.  Look at the jquery documentation.

How you implement the server side depends on what framework you're using.  It's very natural if you use MVC, but if you use WebForms then you probably want a .asmx webservice.

If you don't want to get into javascript then an updating form region is the kind of thing that update panels are quite good for - although I agree they are 'horrible' in that they're a bit of a lazy way of doing ajax.